# Time-dependent, repeatable pseudo-random number

Tags: random, cryptography, stateless

I need to generate a repeatable pseudo-random number that is dependent on the current time and a server secret. For example, this mechanism should generate a new pseudo-random number every minute. The next minute's random number should not be easily predictable.

Furthermore, I need to solve this in a stateless fashion (e.g., without storing a generated value in a database). It is possible that a server node might be asked to create such a number multiple times within the same minute, and it needs to generate the same number each time. Also, multiple server nodes (with the same server secret) need to generate the same number within a given time frame. The purpose of all this is **not** related to solving a security problem (e.g. a token generator), so it's not strictly necessary to use cryptographically secure PRNGs.

Linear-congruential PRNGs produce repeatable series of numbers when initialized with the same seed, so I could seed the PRNG with the combination of time and server secret and get the first random number it produces to meet my criteria. However, this type of PRNG typically uses a simple formula of `next = (current * multiplier + offset) & mask`, and, given a few known times and corresponding random numbers, it seems like it would be not all that hard to figure out the server secret (and then predict all future numbers in advance).

To make this sort of reverse engineering harder, I pull and discard a fixed number (e.g., 1000) of values from the freshly seeded PRNG before I get the "real" random number that I use. My thinking is that reverse-engineering 1000 cycles of `next = (current * multiplier + offset) & mask` would be significantly more difficult that reverse-engineering just a single cycle.

I am wondering if my thinking here is even correct. Is it true that figuring out a linear-congruential PRNG's seed is more difficult based on the 1000th value after seeding than it is for the first value of a freshly seeded generator? If so, how many iterations are sufficient before it stops increasing the difficulty?

If I'm completely off here, what are some better alternatives that fulfill the above stated criteria (repeatability, statelessness)?

Comment: @PeterO. Are you suggesting to calculate `hash(serverSecret + currentTime)` and use the hash value as the "random" number? I hadn't thought of that, but I'm wondering if the hash values would have a similar distribution as values from a PRNG. They'd definitely be difficult to predict, but the question, then, is if hash values make good (i.e., evenly distributed) pseudo-random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way, this is how Time-based one-time passwords ([TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password)s) work, so you can use a similar solution.

To get a time value that changes every N seconds, you can use the following formula.

> floor(timestamp / N)

Then, you can either turn that into a string or interpret it as bytes. Just pass it to something like [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) in order to turn it into a pseudo-random value.

> HMAC(SecretKey, floor(timestamp / N))

Here's a simple implementation in Python. This should be fairly similar in other languages too.

```py
import hmac
import time

# Duration that each value lasts, in seconds
duration = 60

# Generate randomly instead of using a phrase
secret_key = b"very epic secret key"

timestamp = int(time.time())
timestamp = int(timestamp / duration)
timestamp = timestamp.to_bytes(8, "big")

value = hmac.digest(secret_key, timestamp, "sha256")
print(value.hex())
```

You can also turn the value into an integer, or use it in other ways.

```py
value_int = int.from_bytes(value, "big")
```

Comment: I was a little concerned about some of the points made in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76382#76423 regarding the generation of pseudo-random numbers from hash functions. Also, I would say that evenly distributed randomness is not a goal of hash functions, but rather a (frequent) side effect. However, it appears that, at least from a practical perspective, hash functions do produce "good enough" pseudo-random outputs, and (as you mentioned) this is already used in practice in TOTPs.